# Facebook caching open graph image settings won't display correctly for Wordpress site

Tags: php, facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

In the header of our blog I've added the following to set the FB open graph image equal to the highlight image of the post:

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID, 'hero-large') ); ?>"/>
<?php else : ?>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://myblog.com/apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png"/>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then, when I load the page in production, if I look at the html in my head element I see the correct path to the post image:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://myblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/myimage.png"/>
```

However, if I paste a link to that post page into Facebook, three completely random images from past posts elsewhere on my blog appear as the Facebook post image choices.

I don't have any open graph plugins installed and there's no caching issue (or caching plugin) doing this, so I'm confused why Facebook seems to be ignoring my og:image meta tag. Any suggestions on where I should be looking for a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug Insert your url, let the debugger scrape your page and the cache is cleared.